# preference of kmalloc over array in kernel space of a process

Tags: c, unix, memory-management

I was reading some material on memory allocation in kernel space of a process. even though i know that kernel has some small/limited amount of memory(usually 1GB) but why dynamic allocation of memory through kmalloc()is preferred/recommended on defining large arrays?
In other words it is not preferred to allocate large array in kernel space but instead use of dynamically allocated memory is recommended.

My point of contention is that even if a very big array is defined, it will get actual memory only when needed so it will put less pressure on memory. whereas Kmalloc() will assign all demanded memory. 2nd problem is that as kmalloc assign physical memory, finding/preparing demanded size will put extra pressure on system.

But if i read this preference in many sources then there will be some justified reason far away from my reasoning. Can anybody throw light on merits and demerits(if any) for using array and kmalloc() in kernel space

Comment: "even if a very big array is defined, it will get actual memory only when needed"

What makes you think that?

Comment: do you mean that char buf[2048] will be assigned all physical memory at moment of declaration? according to my understanding the assigned memory will be proportional to the number of elements actually used/accessed. when i actually touch the elements of array it will be assigned memory though paging. Am I right?

Comment: In user mode, `char buf[2048]` (can) "allocate" 2K on the stack. If you cross a page boundary halfway through, the kernel handles a page fault and maps in the next page of the buf. In kernel mode, this (probably) doesn't apply.

Comment: please check the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I come across this link http://blog.csdn.net/macyang/article/details/5807008 which explains clearly with simple example the reason for not using arrays in kernel space. the main reason is that in kernel space stack is fixed size (usually two pages) instead of dynamically grow stack. the arrays are stored on stack and very large arrays can not have enough space on stack.

But at the same time this explanation also arise many concerns. if using kamlloc is not efficient as compared to using array (my contention asked) but we are still forced to use it due to fixed size stack, it means fixed size stacks are necessary. The reason for small fixed size stack is limited memory available and fear of stack overflow which in kernel space can be disastrous. So we can not use dynamically grow stacks so we also can not use large arrays to be saved on stack.